# Can I use a common style resource for Interface Builder and if so how?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

Is it possible to define a common style such as a color or font size in Interface Builder and then pick it up in different interfaces or NIBs?

Basically I want to define a constant color in one place for all the labels in my iPhone application, then up that color for all labels, even across different NIBs.

Is this possible?  If so how can I implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into IB for doing that. The closest you can come is to drag the color into one of the little boxes as the bottom of the color picker, which saves it for future use (you can later drag it out of the box into the color well at the top.)

If you really want to define a color or font style in one place and have changes to it take effect everywhere, you'll have to do it in code, in the relevant -awakeFromNib method. One way to do it is to write a function that walks through the view hierarchy, finds all the label views, and applies the color/font to them.

Comment: Thanks Jens - that's what I thought.  I guess I could assign a constant to the tag and then as you say walk the view hierarchy to do a lookup of that constant and assign the appropriate styles. [leaving off snide editorial comments on interface builder]